Power BI DAX: How do I count distinct unique IDs of a dataset that are present more than once and that are associated with another unique ID?
In my use case, I'm collecting the attendance of those who have attended all my pervious events. I am trying to identify how many attendees who have attended my other events more than once are attending 1 specific event.
For example: I have had 200 events that have an overall attendance count of 18,450 people. 6,064 are distinct attendees, and of those attendees, 3,957 have attended more than 1 event. If I've selected Event ID: A1234, which had 1,734 attendees, I'm trying to find all the attendees of Event ID: A1234 that have attended other events. If the out come is 3 recurring attendees or 50, I'd like to know how well I retain my guests for the future.
I tried the below, but it only counts the overall count regardless of my selection. In my case the count remains 3,957 if I select all events, an event that had 2 attendees, or an event that had 1,734 attendees.
NOTE: PIDM = Each attendee's Unique ID
RepeatAttendeesCount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(TEST_EVENT_REPORT[PIDM])),
    FILTER(
        ALL(TEST_EVENT_REPORT),
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(TEST_EVENT_REPORT),
            FILTER(
                ALL(TEST_EVENT_REPORT),
                TEST_EVENT_REPORT[PIDM] = EARLIER(TEST_EVENT_REPORT[PIDM])
            )
        ) > 1
    )
)


Can you share some input data ? Your model ?

Sure, use the link to access some sample data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LDJ7eHvjik6jwNJj1k9oMm01KPWNyo4IAQCbuK0RjRs/edit?usp=sharing

I just requested access

In my case the count remains 3,957 if I select all events, an event that had 2 attendees, or an event that had 1,734 attendees.
You need to exclude the "Event ID:" using ALLEXCEPT() maybe!, If you would share a sample of your data, may be I could try writing some DAX for it.
